# Using an AWS Elastic Load Balancer for MySQL Cluster

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I have a web server which connects to a MySQL cluster (it's Galera cluster)... the cluster works fine (if I update a record on the first instance of MySQL, it is automatically updated on the second instance). The problem is I need a load balancer between the web server and MySQL instances...

So What I have done is to setup an AWS Network Load Balancer (NLB works on Network Layer, TCP in my case)... I have added the 2 instances of MySQL to the NLB's Target group (their private IPs).

[image]

Now I go ahead an update the connection string in my Web Server to connect to the NLB:

```
<add name="MyDB" connectionString="Server=my-nlb-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com; Port=3306; Database=mydb; Uid=user1; Pwd=mypassword; Protocol=TCP" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

But I get the following error:

> [MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the
>   specified MySQL hosts.]    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
>   +1734    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open() +60    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
>   settings) +309
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection() +18
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection() +290
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver() +151
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection() +60
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() +1588
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) +182
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection)

When I try to connect to MySQL from my web server, I get the following:

[image]

[image]

This indicates that the web server is able to reach the MySQL instance through the NLB, but I don't know why the connection string is not working.

I have opened all the IPs on port 3306 , and I can connect to MySQL through NLB from my local computer which is not in the VPC:

[image]

But the web server connection string is not working...

---

I am not entirely sure if it's even possible to use an NLB for this purpose?

Comment: What does your security group look like? Telnet uses TCP, yeah? I dunno off the top of my head what protocol the MySQL driver uses - but maybe it's not TCP?

Comment: @DanielC: thanks, The security group opens port 3306 within the VPC, and the Load Balancer target group uses TCP on port 3306... MySQL uses TCP...

Comment: So to be clear, the LoadBalancer SG doesn't differ from the RDS Instance's SGs? They both allow the same ingress? What does the web server look like? If it's forwarding a request from some client outside of the VPC, is it possible the SG thinks it isn't originating from the VPC? Like from someone's browser? That would explain why the web server fails but the direct connection doesn't

Comment: Web server is a different SG, and DBs are in a different SG, but I have opened 3306 port, the DBs are not RDS actually, I am managing my own MySQL DBs. WebServer and DBs inside the same VPC though

Comment: Just checking if you've managed to solve this issue? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: @SujayDSa: I couldn't get the network load balancer working. I have multiple MySQL instaces, the straight forward solution was to use a multihost connectionstring, but MySQL Connector/Net had a bug, and was not working with multiple host... The bug is fixed now (after 3 years),  [Connector/Net 8.0.19](https://insidemysql.com/)  so i no longer need a network load balancer.

Comment: I had my db instance in private subnets behind a NAT GW and wanted to expose a specific port using an internet-facing NLB. This can be achieved if you also have public subnets created - first prerequisite. Second is that the instance security group rules will reflect on the NLB so open the port in the db instance SG to listen on the port you want and specify the tcp protocol. On the NLB just specify a TCP listener on the same port and create a target group for that listener with the same port specified as the backend port. Hope this helps.